# Viewing a Text-Box after a Button Click PHP

Tags: php, html, onclick, buttonclick

I know this question has been asked before multiple times on StackOverFlow. I have implemented a method to generate a text box for Button click event. But my issue is text box is already visible before performing the clicking. I need to view the text-box when someone clicks the button. I'll put my coding down below.

Coding for the text-field

```
 <div id="inputField" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />
          </div>
```

Coding for the Button click event

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('inputField').style.display = 'block';">Click me</a>
```

Just to make more sense, I'll attach a screenshot of my coding and the graphical view of the form.[image: Coding][image: Form Screenshot]

I'm kindly requesting from everyone not to mark this question as duplicate. I did my best to fix this issue by my own. Though I'm a newbie to this field I couldn't make it up. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the html with:

```
<form method="post" action="?btnpressed=1"> 
    <a href="" name="btn">Click me</a>
</form>
```

And in the php:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['btnpressed']{
        if(isset($_POST['btn']{ ?>
            <div id="inputField" style="display:none;">
                <input type="text" id="textInput" value="" />
            </div>
        <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I hope this helps...